# Farbic.js: Is there any way to save url instead of paths of svg image in the Json generated by JSON.stringify(canvas)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fabricjs

I'm trying to save fabric.js canvas to the server, but I got a lot of svg images. I loaded them from URL (fabric.loadSVGFromURL). When I use JSON.stringify(this.canvas), it saves the paths of the svg images into a Json. If I saved all the paths of them, the Json file will be too large, so I'm wondering if there is anyway that I can save only the url src of these SVG images (also I need to be able to load them to the canvas as well).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally speaking you can but it will require to take care of the load process. You will need to load the source file first and after apply the rest of the block options (fill, scale, width,height). Do you have a fiddle in order to support you?

Comment: @MariusTurcu Thanks for your help, but I decided to use fabric.Image.fromURL instead. The only problem is that, in this way, the SVGs must have width and height to show on fabric canvas. I have to ask the art group to provide images with width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to change paths of `svg` you can just use svg as image. It will work like this:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", { width: 600, height: 600 });

fabric.Image.fromURL("https://svgsilh.com/svg/309620.svg", (img) => {
  img.scaleToWidth(200);
  canvas.add(img);
  console.log(canvas.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: It seems to work, but some of the SVG images don't have width and height property. The canvas cannot show them using Image.fromURL without these two properties. Is there any way to force the images to have width and height other than changing their path code?

Comment: I don't know this way. In my project I just added these properties to all of svg images. They were equal to viewBox values.

Comment: There is another problem, I don't know if you are aware of it. If we use this way to show SVG images, the image can be stretched horizontally only ( or vertically only ) on Chrome, but on firefox, you cannot change the aspect ratio of SVG images.